# Robust solution for verify error messages on the page with Java+Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Situation: Given a complex webapp connected to external systems. If an external system is down, there could be 2 options.

1. case: Big fat stacktrace in a div appears. Locator div class: `errorPage`.
2. case: the application still works, but a warning error msg appears top of the page. Locator: `span class=message message-error`.

The whole framework was implemented Java, Selenium Webdriver with Page Object/Page Factory pattern.

I'm looking for a robust solution to verify the page doesn't have any error in the following cases:

Navigate to the appropriate page, and when the new page initialized, check there is any error on the page (I need to check both cases)
I perform something on the page, search, click on something, and verify error doesn't appear on the page. non of them.
My check error method:

```
public void checkError() {
    if(errorPage.size() > 0) {
        try {
            throw new TestException("Unexpected error appears: " + errorPage.get(0).getText());
        } catch (TestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(One of) my wait method:

```
public void waitForPageLoaded() {

    if (driver.findElements(By.className("errorPage")).size() > 0) {

        try {
            throw new UnexpectedException("Unexpected error:" + driver.findElement(By.id("errorTrace")).getText());
        } catch (UnexpectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("complete");
            }
        };
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(expectation);
    }

}
```

Simple if else statement with isDisplayed method doesn't work, because I got NoSuchElementException when the error doesn't appear on the page.

The method above can be used in different cases, but I would like to collect everything in one solution in a generic way. DRY solution is my idea.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: The driver already waits by default for the ready state, so it's useless to wait for it in your script. And instead of hiding a generic error assertion in a generic waiter, you should assert explicitly the error in your tests with a positive and negative case.

Comment: Could you give me an example here please? Totally understood what you are saying, but handling positive negative case with two different output is not clear for me.

Comment: @FlorentB. Selenium only waits for ready state on `driver.get()`... not on clicks or any other user-triggered navigation. I'm not sure about `.back()` and the like.

Comment: @JeffC, the specification says that the driver has to wait for the complete state when a click causes a navigation or when `Back/Forward/Refresh` is called. I'm quite sure that it's the case with Chrome, though last time I checked the geckodriver still had issues to detect a new page, especially when the navigation is triggered from a composite action. The only case I'm aware of is that the driver doesn't wait if the navigation is triggered via `SendKeys`. Other than that most of the content is nowadays updated via Ajax which has no impact on the status of the page.

Comment: @FlorentB. Well what the spec says vs what actually happens is two different things. I've had plenty of times that I click on a link and pull some text off the page only to find that the page hadn't changed yet so I got text off the old page. That's why I use the method I describe in my answer to make the page object constructor wait for an expected element. For some details, read [this](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html).

Comment: @JeffC, what actually happens with Chrome is what the spec says. The fact is that chromedriver waits by default for the page to be `complete` on every command executed by the client. I can't say the same with Firefox since the geckodriver is unfinished and has still many issues. I think you missed my point which was that it's useless to wait for the page ready state. The case you are describing looks like an Ajax loading, which again has no impact on the page status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several options here. I'll go through a basic case and explain some other potential ways and you can hopefully take this code and tweak it to your preferences.

Basically, each of my page objects determines whether it's loaded or not in the constructor. I have a wait that waits for a specified element using `waitForLocator`. If you have a slow loading portion of the page, choose an element in that area as your locator. If you have a few slow loading areas, you can rewrite this to wait for a list of elements pretty easily to make sure that all the portions of the page are loaded.

After that you implement a method that checks for errors and another method that checks for warnings. You could get fancier and have them return the errors/warnings so you could use them for positive tests, etc.

The page object below is really basic. I'm doing kinda the dumb version of this that just throws an exception if there is an error or warning. You can definitely take those checks out of the constructor, etc. if you don't want your test to fail on error/warning, e.g. you intentionally trigger them and then verify that they exist.

With this approach you don't need to wait until the error message appears. You wait for the `waitForLocator` which indicates your page is done loading... at that point, you can just check for error/warning with no waits.

This is how I implement all my page objects. I put waits in the constructors and then only need to add waits when I've triggered some event on the page, e.g. modal dialog launch. When an event gets triggered, the method that triggers that event waits for an element to be visible that is in the dynamic section of the page, e.g. wait for container element of dialog to be visible.

```
public class PageObject
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By waitForLocator = By.id("someId"); // this is a locator for some element on the page that is last to load

    private By errorLocator = By.cssSelector("div.errorPage");
    private By warningLocator = By.cssSelector("span.message.message-error");
    private By buttonLocator = By.cssSelector("button");

    public PageObject(WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.driver = webDriver;

        // wait for page to finish loading
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(waitForLocator));

        if (errorExists())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("There are errors on the page.");
        }
        if (warningExists())
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("There are warnings on the page.");
        }
    }

    public void clickButton()
    {
        driver.findElement(buttonLocator).click();
    }

    public boolean errorExists()
    {
        return !driver.findElements(errorLocator).isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean warningExists()
    {
        return !driver.findElements(warningLocator).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Your script would look something like the below. I'm using TestNG asserts to verify that no errors/warnings exist.

```
PageObject page = new PageObject(driver);
page.clickButton(); // do something that might trigger an error or warning
Assert.assertFalse(page.errorExists(), "Verify no errors exist");
Assert.assertFalse(page.warningExists(), "Verify no warnings exist");
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, it is very comprehensive answer. I try to use this idea and will let you know the results!

Comment: It works well, thanks for you help! However I faced another problem, my cucumber-jvm hooks cannot handle multiple tests because after the first test, hook closes my driver and I got session Id is null error. However it is another problem, another question :)